# Woocommerce change the file attached to a downloadable product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm brand new to using WordPress. I'm working on standing up an eCommerce site to sell subscriptions using woo-commerce. The nature of the business is to sell my subscribers a zip file with multiple reports. There would be multiple products a user can subscribe to & each product will come with its own zip file.

I'm trying to solve the following problems -

1. The downloadable zip file changes every day for every product. Is there a way to programmatically upload these files into woo-commerce? I'm thinking maybe SFTP via command line)? Any other ways to do this?
2. How could I update the same product with a different file to be downloaded? How could I do this programmatically, please? Will the URL be the same for the customer? If not, how to get around this problem, please?

My apologies if this question sounds dumb. I am badly stuck and being a newbie to this isn't helping. Please if someone could guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way out is to do this manually or to use a separate file server  like google drive, create shared folder, put your files in it & then provide the link to the shared directory as an external link for the product (not file as file changes however so often). Took ages to work this out.